# Code auditing and/or fuzzing - Books and resources

Tags: exploit, professional-education, audit, code-review, fuzzing

I've read the 'Shellcoder's Handbook' as well as 'The Art of Exploitation', and appreciated both a lot. Now I'm looking for additional resources delving into vulnerability spotting, code auditing, and maybe fuzzing. Any recommendation for a book or must-read online resources of great interest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for fuzzing take a look at:

- Fuzzing: Brute Force Vulnerability Discovery (ISBN 0321446119)
- Fuzzing for Software Security Testing and Quality Assurance (ISBN 1596932147)

for code review:

- Peer Reviews in Software: A Practical Guide (ISBN 0201734850)

Answer (score 2):

For static code analysis I can recommend this:

- Secure Programming with Static Analysis (Brian Chess/ Jacob West)

Answer (score 1):

The web application hackers handbook is good book in web applications security and it is exploits .

[A Bug Hunter's Diary: A Guided Tour Through the Wilds of Software Security](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593273851)
this is also very good I didn't complete it though.

Also OWASP/WASC guides are too good for Vulnerability Detection and Testing .

and Google is your best friend always.

Comment: Thanks Ali, I'll have a look at the Bug Hunter's Diary. I've already read the WAHH which is very good indeed, but I'm only looking for system exploits there. Also google can be helpful but there is way too much stuff here, that's why I asked here for only the **best** resources :)

Comment: you mean exploit development/penetration testing related books and materials